# Finding the appropriate executable in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a Makefile that needs to execute the program `foo1`, which is usually provided by the operating system. Some operating systems provide this binary with a different name, `foo2`.

I'm trying to figure out how to best test for the correct executable and exist if neither doesn't exist. I've had a few approaches but they all seem ugly and I figured there might be a more appropriate way to do this.

I tried this:

```
FOO = $(shell which foo foo2)

target:
   @which $(FOO) > /dev/null
   $(FOO)
```

I don't find this very elegant because if both `foo` and `foo2` exist on the system, `which` will actually return two lines. It's also weird that I call `which` twice and that I rely on an error being emitted when I don't pass anything to the second `which`.

In short, what's a better way?

Comment: `FOO = $(shell which foo foo2 false | head -1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
FOO := $(firstword $(shell which foo foo1))
ifeq ($(FOO),)
  $(error Cannot find foo or foo1)
endif

target:
        $(FOO)
```

Or if you don't like using make's `error` function you can use:

```
target:
        @[ -n "$(FOO)" ] || { echo "Cannot find foo or foo1"; exit 1; }
```

Note this will not work if you have any pathnames with spaces in them in your `PATH`... but that's a much larger problem to solve anyway.