# Makefile: Find which variant of executable name is available on the system

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have an application that is available under different name under different linux distro.
e.g. in ubuntu it is `foo` and in RHEL it is `foo.ruby2.7`
Given a list of known variants is there is single line directive way to select the available executable ?
something like

```
PROG = find_foo(foo foo.ruby2.7 ...)
runit:
   $(PROG) $(OPTIONS)
```

Or is a bunch of

```
ifneq (,$(shell command -v foo))
PROG=foo
```

the only way to go?

Note: [Finding the appropriate executable in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444631/finding-the-appropriate-executable-in-a-makefile) is a partial answer, but it does not handle the case where the command is an alias.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence.  Make won't run aliases, in general, since the shell it invokes is a POSIX shell and it's not started in interactive mode.  Try this: `alias ls='echo hi'; /bin/sh -c 'ls'` and note that it doesn't run your alias, it runs `ls`.  This is basically what make is doing.

Comment: @MadScientist, assume I have 3 servers with different exucatables foo,foo3.1 foo.ruby2.7 and the server with foo executable actually has it defined as an alias e.g. `alias foo=foo.2.0` .
if I use the method in the linked solution( `FOO=$(shell which  foo  foo3.1 foo.ruby2.7)` ) on the server with alias. FOO will contain `foo: aliased to foo.2.0` and executing $(FOO) in my recipe wont work.

Comment: No, it won't.  At least not portably.  Here is what I see: `alias ls='echo hi'; /bin/sh -c 'which ls'` gives me an output of `/bin/ls`.  `which` is not a shell built-in, in POSIX shell, so it doesn't know about shell constructs like aliases.  On some systems, but not all, `/bin/sh` is really bash and that might have `which` as a built in, but even there it is invoked as a non-interactive shell so it won't load `~/.bashrc` unless you set `BASH_ENV`, etc.  In general you cannot use shell aliases in make recipes.  Which is a *good* thing.